# Limit of a sum of fractions

Tags: limits

$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\dots+\frac{1}{2n}$

How to find $\lim a_n$?

Comment: Look at it as a Riemann sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Eulero-Mascheroni : $$\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k} - \log{n} \rightarrow \gamma$$ $$\sum_{k = 1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} - \log{2n} \rightarrow \gamma$$ so $$\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} - \log{2n} +\log{n} \rightarrow 0$$ and then$$\sum_{k = n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{k} \rightarrow \log{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

As Daniel Fisher suggested, rewrite  1/(n+k) as (1/n) 1/(1+k/n) and you are done through integration. I am sure you can take from here.

---

*Below is a reformatted version of this answer*

**HINT**

As Daniel Fisher suggested, rewrite  $\dfrac 1{n+k}$ as $\dfrac {1}{n} \dfrac {1}{1+\frac k n}$ and you are done through integration. I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: Do you mind if I type your answer in $\LaTeX$ below yours, keeping your version?

Comment: @GitGud. I am sorry for that (I even wrote it in my profile). I became almost blind a couple of years ago and I do not "see" what I type. Beside plain ASII, everything is very hard to me and I did not find a way to learn LaTex in my conditions. Be sure I really apologize. I thank you very much if you accept to LaTeXify for me. Cheers.

Comment: I read your profile, I knew about your condition before I posted my comment. That's why I'm asking for your permission to add a $\LaTeX$ version of your answer (in your answer), while keeping the original version.

Comment: Again, thank you very much for doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Brutally speaking, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{n+k}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1k\right)-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k\right)\simeq\ln2n-\ln n=\ln\frac{2n}n=\ln2.$$ Rigourously, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{n+k}=\frac1n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{1+\frac kn}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}=\ln(1+x)|_0^1=\ln2.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k} = \sum_{k = n}^{2n - 1}{1 \over k + 1} 
 = \sum_{k = 0}^{2n - 1}{1 \over k + 1} - \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over k + 1}
=\bracks{\Psi\pars{2n + 1} - \Psi\pars{1}}  - \bracks{\Psi\pars{n + 1} - \Psi\pars{1}} 
$$
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k} = 
\Psi\pars{2n + 1} - \Psi\pars{n + 1}
$$
Since $\Gamma\pars{z + 1} \sim \root{2\pi}z^{z + 1/2}\expo{-z}$ when
$\verts{z} \gg 1$, $\Psi\pars{z + 1} \sim \ln\pars{z} + {1 \over 2z}$
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k} \sim
\bracks{\ln\pars{2n} + {1 \over 2\pars{2n}}} - \bracks{\ln\pars{n} + {1 \over 2n}}
=
\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 4n}
$$
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over n + k} = \ln\pars{2}}
$$